# Form element deleted from first row of WP_Lists_Table

Tags: wp-list-table

I was trying to add a small input into the posts columns and in the markup that looks like it is working just fine. Using the standard

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'kia_post_columns', 20 );

function post_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['custom'] = 'Custom';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'kia_render_columns' );

function render_columns( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'custom' :
            echo '<form name="test" class="shipping_tracking"><input type="text" value="bacon"/></form>';
        break;
    }
}
```

When what I was trying to achieve (ajax-save input value as post meta) didn't work, I started examining the markup via Chrome's dev tools (and Firefox's too).... and the `<form>` element is gone on the first row. To visualize, I also threw a little jQuery at it:

```
$( '.shipping_tracking' ).each( function() { 

            $(this).css('border', '3px solid red');
});
```

And here is the weird result:
[image: result]

What could WordPress be doing such that it would remove the `<form>` element from the first row... presumably after the page is loaded, because if I View Source it is still in place as I would expect.

Comment: Actually entire post list is wrapped in form, so I guess that WordPress remove your form trying to resolve a conflict with nested forms. I think you can add the inputs without forms. If you plan to get data via ajax you can still do, and if you plan to submit in the "classic" way you can: you have to get data form the "big" form that wrap everything.

Comment: But the nested form is seemingly allowed in the other rows? As well as it appears in the markup. I can do the inputs without forms, but then I got stuck with the enter keypress submitting the whole page, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Nested forms are not valid html. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element *"Content model: Flow content, but with no form element descendants."* ... I think you can block the enter keypress via js

Comment: Still confused as to why it'd be that way only in the first row, but if you will repost your comment about invalid markup as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I don't think my comment answers your Q, really. Let's see if someone with better js expertice can proper answer it...

Comment: Fair enough. @toscho mentioned on twitter that it might have to do with the bulk edit form?

Comment: It was my first thought too, but fields of bulk edit form are not wrapped in any form... but, sincerly my knowledge of internal WP javascripts is very shallow